# Deriving $E[g(X)h(Y)]$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, independence

My attempt:

$\sum_x \sum_y g(x)h(y)f_x(x)f_y(y)$?
Is this the correct way?

---

**Problem:** Let $X$ take one of two values ${x_1, x_2}$ with $p_1 = P(X = x_1)$ and let $Y$ take one of two values ${y_1, y_2}$ with $q_1 = P(Y = y_1)$. Let these two discrete random variables be independent. Derive $E[g(X)h(Y )]$ and compare this to $E[g(X)] × E[h(Y )]$.

Comment: Because $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables, your attempt is correct.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @HasanHeydari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ${{\mathsf E[g(X)\,h(Y)] ~}{= \sum_x\sum_y g(x)\,h(y)\,f_X(x)\,f_Y(y) \\ = {p_1q_1g(x_1)h(y_1) +p_1(1-q_1)g(x_1)h(y_2)\\+(1-p_1)q_1 g(x_2)h(y_1)+ (1-p_1)(1-q_1)g(x_2)h(y_2) }}}$

Similarly $\mathsf E[g(X)]\;\mathsf E[h(Y)] ~{= (\sum_x g(x)\,f_X(x))(\sum_y h(y)\,\,f_Y(y))\\ =}$

How do they compare.